# What kind of algorithm applies?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sequence

***TLDR: I'm effectively looking for an algorithm that would give me a combination of the minimum amount of total messages needed , whether they be "sequential" AND/OR "layered" in order to get to the final result.***

===
For a hotel imagine 12 consecutive weeks.

For each of these weeks a price of 100$ exists.

The hotel’s manager decides to change the prices of all these weeks as such

[image]

His system currently allows him only to send “price change” messages “**sequentially**” like so:

1. Week 1 to Week 2 = 120 $
2. Week 3 to Week 4 = 150 $
3. Week 5 to Week 6 = 120 $
4. Week 7 to Week 9 = 200 $
5. Week 10 = 120$
6. Week 11 = 250$
7. Week 12 = 120$

However, in this case he understands that it would be more efficient to send out the messages 
in a “**layered**” manner like so:

1. Week 1 to Week 12 = 120 $
2. Week 3 to Week 4 = 150 $
3. Week 7 to Week 9 = 200 $
4. Week 11 = 250$

**Which algorithm allows the manager to always calculate the optimal “layered” option??** so that he may systematically choose the most efficient manner of sending out the messages, no matter how many weeks are concerned  and bearing in mind that some weeks will not necessarily have their prices changed.

**I'm effectively looking for an algorithm that would give me a combination of the minimum amount of total messages needed , whether they be "sequential" AND/OR "layered" in order to get to the final result**. Those such an algorithm exist ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Sorry, but this question is way too broad.  Take the [tour], and read [ask].  Why tagged with XML?

Comment: Ok sorry :( Well I am using XML as a messaging service and I am pretty sure people who use a lot of XML are very familiar with this type of issue, perhaps a mistake to have tagged it like that ? Sorry ...

Comment: So basically you want to find the price that occurs most often? Count occurrences of each price and use the one that appears most often as optimal option.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but no, finding the price that occurs most often would presume I would go systematically for the "layered" option, but the layered option could potentially be more tedious than the "sequential" option, so just counting won't give me systematically the right option. I'm effectively looking for an algorithm that would give me a combination of the minimum amount of messages whether "sequential" AND/OR "layered" needed to get to the final result. Those such an algorithm exist ?

Comment: You could use dynamic programming to solve this in O(n^4) time and O(n^2) space, but I suspect there may be an even faster approach.  How large is a typical value of n?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I think `O(n^3)` space.  For each interval it can matter what value is currently set if no finer grained updates are done.  Though admittedly this only matters if that value actually appears in the interval.  But in practice with a top down memoized recursion I think you'll generally visit very little of the theoretically possible space.

Comment: @btilly: good point - I'll post some example code

Comment: I solved this problem about 40 years ago to compress files that were meant to be sent to a line printer to print a poster picture. I wish I could remember how I did it. Probably didn't guarantee the most optimal configuration, just settled for something "good enough".

Comment: the sequential option is never less messages than the layered option, even when all numbers are different.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a top-down memoized recursion in Python that should solve this problem in O(n^4) time (actually slightly longer because it is also keeping track of the moves to make - but this could be optimized away):

```python
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not self.memo.has_key(args):
            self.memo[args] = self.fn(*args)
        return self.memo[args]

@Memoize
def best_messages(a,b,value=None):
    """Return moves needed to make range old[a:b] have the target values

If value is not None, it means the range has been set to the given value
"""
    if value is None:
        while a<b and new[a]==old[a]:
            a+=1
        while a<b and new[b-1]==old[b-1]:
            b-=1     
    else:
        # Skip values that are correct
        while a<b and new[a]==value:
            a+=1
        while a<b and new[b-1]==value:
            b-=1     
    if a==b:
        return [] # Nothing to change

    best = None
    for s in range(a,b):
        for e in range(s+1,b+1):
            target = new[s]
            if target==new[e-1]:
                moves = [ (s,e,target) ] + best_messages(s,e,target) + best_messages(a,s,value) + best_messages(e,b,value) 
                if best is None or len(moves)<len(best):
                    best = moves
    return best

old = [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]
new = [120,120,150,150,120,120,200,200,200,120,250,120]
for s,e,value in best_messages(0,len(old))  :
    print "Week {} to Week {} = {}".format(s+1,e,value)
```

The basic principle is that it only makes sense to consider updates where we set the first and last in the update to the final target value because otherwise we can make the update shorter and still take the same number of moves.

### Update

I think it can be optimized to work in O(n^3) time if you change:

```
for s in range(a,b):
```

to

```
s=a
```